# Try on Making A Random sudoku 3x3 on Java - BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej, sudoku

iam newbie in this so i will ask straightly and if smb can help me that would be appreciated. Iam trying to make a Sudoku Game in BlueJ and until now i havent got any help from google searches and staff so iam posting here.

I need my sudoku firstly to be a random puzzle when pressing a button to start new.

Then the main concept and correct me if iam wrong is to built one random table which will be the solution for the user and one table where user can see 3 numbers only from the table and pick the other. With Comparing of 2 tables, users and solution the programm can see if the user has it correct.

Until now i have this code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MyFrame extends Frame
{
    private double[] data;
    private Button avgButton,minButton,maxButton,rndomButton;
    private Button quit;

    public MyFrame(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        resize(200,200);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        quit=new Button("QUIT");
        rndomButton=new Button("RANDOM");
        add(rndomButton);
        add(quit);
    }

    public int Array()
    {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  n = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
            int  y = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            int value;
            int[][] board = new int[3][3];
            value=board[0][0];
            int z=board[0][0];
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {

                    do{
                    board[i][0]=n;
                }while (board[i][0]!=board[i-1][0]&&board[i][0]!=board[i-2][0]);
            }
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                    do{
                    board[0][j]=n;
                }while (board[0][j]!=board[0][j-1]&&board[0][j]!=board[0][j-2]);
            }
            for(i=1;i<3;i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<3;j++)
                {
                    do{
                    board[i][j]=n;
                }while (board[i][j]!=board[i-1][j]&&board[i][j]!=board[i-2][j]&&board[i][j]!=board[i][j-1]&&board[i][j]!=board[i][j-2]);
                }
            }
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                z=board[i][j];
            }
            }
           return z;
    }

    public boolean action(Event evt,Object arg)
    {

       if(evt.target.equals(rndomButton))
         message("Array: "+Array());
        else
        if(evt.target.equals(quit))
         System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I dont know if it is correct because when i try to return z value its just a window pops up with nothing in there.

Note if i get return z in lasts for i get an error on bluej.

Sorry for my programming skills.

I hope u can help me or at least recommend me some links to look at.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you've jumped into your coding a little too soon.  It appears that you need to better define your approach to the problem.  First, think about how you would solve it by hand.  Break that down into steps, and write those steps down.  Then, make your code model your solution step by step.

For example, if you think about building your board one row at a time, then you would write down something like, "For the first row, take 1, 2, 3, and rearrange them in random order..."  If you think. instead, about building your board one digit at a time, you might write, "Place a 1 in a random location in the first row.  Place a 1 in a random location in the second row, but avoid a conflict with the first row.  Place a 1 in the only remaining column in the third row.

With your second digit, you'll encounter more constraints-- instead of just selecting any column at random from the first row, you'll need to select randomly from an *available* column.

```
1 2 .
. 1 .
. . 1
```

In the example above, when placing a 2 in your second row, how do you determine which is available?  (One choice leads to a solution, the other to a dead-end).  Once you're able to articulate the steps you would take to solve the problem by hand, writing the code becomes much easier and the small pieces you may get stuck on become easier to address.